# Replicated Backup & Archival Solution?

Tags: backup, sync, incremental-backup

I'm attempting to design a system for backup and archival, and I'm frustrated that I can see all the pieces I need, but can't seem to find anything that brings them all together.  I want a system that has:

- Physical redundancy (i.e. RAID, ReFS, ZFS)
- Bit-rot protection (i.e. ReFS, ZFS, FlexRAID)
- Expandable storage pooling (i.e. FlexRAID)
- Peer-to-Peer Synchronization (No cloud storage!) (i.e. BitTorrent Sync)
- Incremental file versioning (i.e. Dropbox, ZFS, Git)

I'd like to arrange some sort of software stack to create a set-it-and-forget-it type of secure file storage node, and slowly build a network of these nodes in geographically distant locations (with family, friends), which could then be used to backup all of our computers and files.

The closest I've come to this is BitTorrent Sync on top of FlexRAID, which would achieve most of the goals except file versioning.  I'd appreciate any insights on how I could achieve this.  Thanks!